# Why do I now have to specify the exact type when checking through the $I->seeInField function? Can this be fixed?

Tags: codeception

I had written acceptance tests in Codeception that worked.

Then I updated Codeception, Selenium, and changed the PHP version to a newer one. Ran the autotests, they started failing on the `$I->seeInField` function.

I noticed that if I specify the exact type, then the tests work:

```
$I->seeInField($selector, strval($val));
```

Can I make it so that I don't have to specify the exact type? To make it work like before:

```
$I->seeInField($selector, $val);
```

Comment: Please provide full error message and a stacktrace. seeInField method doesn't specify expected type of $value parameter: https://github.com/Codeception/module-webdriver/blob/0f26e63e760aa93b8448013c77283598b0658e78/src/Codeception/Module/WebDriver.php#L1431-L1435

Also specify what version of codeception/module-webdriver you use,

Comment: StackOverflow is not the right place for bug reports, next time please raise an issue in appropriate place, e. g. https://github.com/Codeception/module-webdriver/issues or https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues